# How to download nodejs version 6.10.3 in Windows subsystem for Linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm looking to downgrade my version of nodejs from v6.11.2 to v6.10.3.. I don't know of a way to download a specific version since the closest option from nodesoure.com is `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -`, which gives me v6.11. It doesn't appear that `nvm` or `n` work for WSL and `nvm for windows` wouldn't work since I'm using bash on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I use nvm (node version manager) to manage the versions of node and npm that I'm using inside WSL.

Install instructions here: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash
nvm install 6.10.3
nvm use 6.10.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading node package works exactly like downgrading any other package in linux:

`sudo apt-get install <package-name>=<package-version-number>`  OR

`sudo apt-get -t=<target release> install <package-name>`

Additionally use

- `apt-cache showpkg <package-name>` lists all available versions. (h/t [Sparhawk][])
- `apt-mark hold <package-name>`  "holds" the package at the current version, preventing automatic upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

## n now works on Windows 10 (Windows Subsystem For Linux):

#### Windows version

*Windows 10 Home, Version   10.0.17134 Build 17134*

#### Version of N

*i.e. n --version output: 2.1.11*

#### How I installed N

Start up windows subsystem for linux bash prompt by typing Win key followed by `wsl`
Then, install using the following sequence:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n lts
sudo npm install npm@lts -g
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/aal/.config
```

IMPORTANT NOTE:

- change the name in the path when using the `chown` command above to reflect your home directory in WSL.
- Then, exit the shell and start it up again.

After restarting the WSL bash window:

```
$ node --version
  v8.11.2
$ npm --version
  5.6.0
```

Tried installing other node versions, using

```
sudo n install latest
```

And got:

```
$ node --version
v10.4.0
$ npm --version
6.1.0
```

#### NOTE: nvm did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on node v6.11.2 and want to downgrade to node v6.10.3, uninstall node & follow below instructions for the version you want:

## Remove current version

```
sudo apt remove -y nodejs
```

## Setup sources for your version

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
```

## Install Node again

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```